# What is the center of buoyancy for objects submerged in two liquids?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-statics, buoyancy

Suppose a solid object is submerged into two immiscible liquids stacked one above the other in such a way that some part of solid is in air some in 1 liquid and some in another liquid.

Can we say the center of buoyancy is the center of mass of the submerged part? Or it is that there are two centers of buoyancy: one for the part submerged in the first liquid, and another for the part in the other liquid?

I can solve sums considering it to be two parts but if the first statement is true then it will make problems easier.

Comment: Just like centre of mass where we _weight_ the positions by the masses at those places , we can probably apply the same technique to take a weighted sum of all points of the object to find the centre of buoyancy. I have not heard of such a thing however. Still it is very doable.

Comment: What is the center of buoyancy?

Comment: It is like the center of gravity, a force center,  under this as the orign, $\sum \vec r \times \vec F_b = 0$. because the  different liquids give different force, the center of force will not same as the center of mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site https://www.britannica.com/science/centre-of-buoyancy

defines center of buoyancy as the center of mass of the displaced liquid.  If you have enough information to find that, the densities and depths of the liquids, and the shape and mass of the object - then you can find the center of buoyancy.

Comment: oh ok i kinda forgot about a important part in the definition center of "mass of displaced liquid". thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

If the object is simply floating, the center of buoyancy would have to directly below the center of gravity. If other forces are applied, it would have to shift to keep the sum of torques equal to zero.

Comment: wait really? center of buoyancy depends on other forces too?

Comment: Consider a boat at anchor in a current.  The anchor rope pulls the bow down. More displacement of water toward the bow shifts the buoyant force in that direction and compensates for the pull of the rope.

Comment: isnt it just because the weight of water displaced increases as it goes down a bit.

Comment: The rope introduces a torque which must be met by shifting the buoyant force from under the center of gravity.